# Return the values from a 2D array

Tags: c

I have a function that takes the information from a 1D vector and split it in 8 columns from an array:

```
void ochoCanales(unsigned char * data)
{
    UINT64 INTEGRATE1 = 0, INTEGRATE2 = 0, P, Q;
    P = 0, Q = 0;
    double ** adc_val;
    adc_val = (double *)malloc(8 * sizeof(double*));
    int u;
    for (u = 0;u < 8 + 1;u++)
    {
        adc_val[u] = (double *)malloc(VER_LENGTH*BUFFER_ADC / 8 * sizeof(double *));
    }

    while (P + 1 <= BULK_BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        INTEGRATE1 = data[P + 7];
        INTEGRATE1 = (INTEGRATE1 << 8) | data[P + 6];
        INTEGRATE1 = (INTEGRATE1 << 8) | data[P + 5];
        INTEGRATE1 = (INTEGRATE1 << 8) | data[P + 4];
        INTEGRATE1 = (INTEGRATE1 << 8) | data[P + 3];
        INTEGRATE1 = (INTEGRATE1 << 8) | data[P + 2];
        INTEGRATE1 = (INTEGRATE1 << 8) | data[P + 1];
        INTEGRATE1 = (INTEGRATE1 << 8) | data[P];
        INTEGRATE2 = data[P + 15];
        INTEGRATE2 = (INTEGRATE2 << 8) | data[P + 14];
        INTEGRATE2 = (INTEGRATE2 << 8) | data[P + 13];
        INTEGRATE2 = (INTEGRATE2 << 8) | data[P + 12];
        INTEGRATE2 = (INTEGRATE2 << 8) | data[P + 11];
        INTEGRATE2 = (INTEGRATE2 << 8) | data[P + 10];
        INTEGRATE2 = (INTEGRATE2 << 8) | data[P + 9];
        INTEGRATE2 = (INTEGRATE2 << 8) | data[P + 8];
        P = P + 16;

        adc_val[0][Q] = (INTEGRATE1 & 0x000000000000FFFF);
        adc_val[1][Q] = (INTEGRATE1 & 0x00000000FFFF0000) >> 16;
        adc_val[2][Q] = (INTEGRATE1 & 0x0000FFFF00000000) >> 32;
        adc_val[3][Q] = (INTEGRATE1 & 0xFFFF000000000000) >> 48;
        adc_val[4][Q] = (INTEGRATE2 & 0x000000000000FFFF);
        adc_val[5][Q] = (INTEGRATE2 & 0x00000000FFFF0000) >> 16;
        adc_val[6][Q] = (INTEGRATE2 & 0x0000FFFF00000000) >> 32;
        adc_val[7][Q] = (INTEGRATE2 & 0xFFFF000000000000) >> 48;
        Q++;
        INTEGRATE1 = 0; INTEGRATE2 = 0;
    }
    return adc_val;
}
```

In the main code I have this static array; the dimensions are the same as `adc_val`:

```
double adc_val1[CAN_CANALES][(VER_LENGTH*BUFFER_ADC)/CAN_CANALES];
```

In the main code I would like to do something like this:

```
adc_val1 = ochoCanales(szBufferM);
```

But I get the error:

```
Expression must be modifiable value (adc_val1)
```

Why does this happen? How can I solve this??

Comment: You can't do array assignment.  You need `adc_val1` to be a `double **`, like `adc_val` in the function.  Your function needs to return `double **` too; you have `return adc_val;` at the end of what is currently a function returning `void` so the code shown shouldn't be compiling because of that.  Don't forget to `free()` the array after you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here. To start - your function is of type void, so it doesnt return anything. if you want to return a adcval1  - you should change the signature to show that-

```
double ** ochoCanales(unsigned char * data)
```

More to the point - since in your main code you already statically allocated for a 2D array

```
double adc_val1[CAN_CANALES][(VER_LENGTH*BUFFER_ADC)/CAN_CANALES];
```

**This means:**

1. You can't assign to adc_val1 - and you don't want to. adc_val1 points to some memory block, and if you were to assign another block to it - the first one would be lost.
2. There is no need to allocate more memory inside the function - you already set aside memory for the array. so you don't need:

   ```
   for (u = 0;u < 8 + 1;u++)
   {
      adc_val[u] = (double *)malloc(VER_LENGTH*BUFFER_ADC / 8 * sizeof(double *));
   }
   ```

Now, what you actually want to do, is pass in adc_val1 which you allocated beforehand, and fill it with your values

```
//replace sizeRow, sizeCol with the actual sizes
void ochoCanales(unsigned char * data, double arr[sizeRow][sizeCow])
{
    UINT64 INTEGRATE1 = 0, INTEGRATE2 = 0, P, Q;
    P = 0, Q = 0;
    int u;

    while (P + 1 <= BULK_BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
       //The rest of your code
    }
}
```